# Dynamically created controls causing Null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I am trying to dynamically create controls and give them properties during run time.

I have put my code inside the Page_Init event, when I run my website I can see my controls but when I click on the submit button an error occurrs saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here is the code I have used:

```
    //Creates instances of the Control    
    Label FeedbackLabel = new Label();
    TextBox InputTextBox = new TextBox();
    Button SubmitButton = new Button();
    // Assign the control properties

    FeedbackLabel.ID = "FeedbackLabel";
    FeedbackLabel.Text = "Please type your name: ";
    SubmitButton.ID = "SubmitButton";
    SubmitButton.Text = "Submit";
    InputTextBox.ID = "InputTextBox";
    // Create event handlers
    SubmitButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(SubmitButton_Click);

    // Add the controls to a Panel
    Panel1.Controls.Add(FeedbackLabel);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(InputTextBox);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(SubmitButton);
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an instance of Button for the existing control
    Button SubmitButton = (Button)sender;
    // Update the text on the Button
    SubmitButton.Text = "Submit again!";

    // Create the Label and TextBox controls
    Label FeedbackLabel = (Label)FindControl("FeedbackLabel");
    TextBox InputTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl("InputTextBox");
    // Update the controls
    FeedbackLabel.Text = string.Format("Hi, {0}", InputTextBox.Text);
```

How can I fix this error?

This Is the Stack Trace

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      _Default.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\bilalq\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\Default.aspx.cs:31
>      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +8876158
>      System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +31
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +328

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: @Neil, he said the error occurs when clicking submit. I think it can't find the controls (because they're added to a panel, not directly to the page).

Comment: Down votes seem a little harsh today

Comment: @qablan89, could you please give us some info from the stack trace?  Which line is the exception being thrown from?

Comment: @Valamas agreed, some people forget that we're here to help people.  Clearly they've got out of the wrong side of bed!

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: @qablan89, regarding the stacktrace, which line of the code you've pasted is line 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you declare your controls outside the page_int and do your initialization in the init then use them with their name instead of find control.

Answer (score 3):

As FindControl is not recursive, you have to replace this code :

```
Label FeedbackLabel = (Label)FindControl("FeedbackLabel");
TextBox InputTextBox = (TextBox)FindControl("InputTextBox");
```

by this code :

```
Label FeedbackLabel = (Label)Panel1.FindControl("FeedbackLabel");
TextBox InputTextBox = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("InputTextBox");
```

However, according other answers, you should move the declaration (not the instantiation) outside the method (at class level) in order to easily get an entry for your controls.

Comment: To DoctJones I tried to replace them but it did not work

The error ocurred here 

   Panel1.Controls.Add(FeedbackLabel);

This is the stack trace

Comment: is Panel1 != null at this time ?

Answer (score 2):

try to put your code in the Page_Load instead of Page_Init and also, check for null before  using objects returned by FindControl.

I suspect the object `InputTextBox` is null and it crashes when you try to print its `Text`.

as a general rule just check for null and also for type when casting results of FindControl to something else.

Answer (score 2):

The `FindControl` is failing because it can't find the control and causing a null reference.

Just reference it directly using `FeedbackLabel` as you already have it in your class. Just move the scope outside of your 'Init' method.

```
private Label feedbackLabel = new Label();
private TextBox inputTextBox = new TextBox();
private Button submitButton = new Button();

public void Page_Init(EventArgs e)
{
    feedbackLabel.ID = "FeedbackLabel";
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    feedbackLabel.Text =...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        //-- Create your controls here
    }
```

Comment: Thank you All it works when i commented this statement

FeedbackLabel.Text = string.Format("Hi, {0}", InputTextBox.Text);